Custom SeekBar in android for camrea-app for changing focus value
I'm currently working on developing a camera application for Android, and I'm looking to incorporate a custom SeekBar to allow users to adjust the focus value seamlessly. I've been exploring various options but haven't found a clear guide on implementing this specific feature. Could someone with experience in Android development offer guidance on creating a custom SeekBar for focus adjustment?
I want something like default camera apps seekbar.
Example Image

Are you using XML or Compose?

i am using XML .

nice then, see my answer below

I found some libraries on GitHub which are not exactly as seen in image you provided but, you can use it as a starting point/reference to customize it for your exact needs.

Android Ruler Picker
RuleView

